# Which crimp terminal is crimped correctly?

Tags: connector, tools, terminal, crimp

I've loaded the crimp terminal two different ways in my crimper, but I haven't the experience to say which is correct.

Cursory web research doesn't seem to answer the question.

Edit: this is the first halves of butt connectors. The other halves aren't crimped yet. (The UI here wouldn't let me upload the whole photo.)

[image: two crimped connectors, one on a black wire and one on a white wire]

Comment: the left one, because it did not mash the wire

Answer (score 3):

The one with the white cable. Remove the red plastic to see why. The copper is contacted in the middle, and there's a small tube that you simply have to squeeze. At the end however there's two flaps that need to be bent inside to stick on the cable insulation.

Comment: Exactly.  You should always make test crimps and do an autopsy on them.  You'll learn quickly what works and what doesn't.